# Knockoutjs: unable to correctly set initial dropdown value

Tags: knockout.js, drop-down-menu, binding, subscription

The code is too complicated to show, but the problem itself is relatively simple.

I work on a property information system for a local government.  Users can search for a property and see information about it.  Some properties can have more than one account, so there's a dropdown list that is populated with options and the account for which the user searched.  However, I can't set the chosen account properly.

Here's the reason.  I set up a subscription so that, when users choose a different account to view, the correct information is shown.  However, when the bindings are initially set, both the options and the value binding fire off the subscription.  The value binding's value is correct, but the options binding uses the first item in the array -- and that is always runs after the value binding, so the binding is usually incorrect.

Is there a way to write a custom binding so the options binding does not set off the subscription?  Alternatively, is there a way to set the initial binding so that it doesn't set off the subscription?

Comment: Surely there is code - as in, a *minimal test-case* - to demonstrate/reproduce this issue?

Comment: (Also, do make sure to read up on [`optionsValue`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).)

Answer (score 1):

Without code, it's very hard to be specific. If your code is 'too complicated', you're either doing things terribly wrong, or you're doing things even more wrong.

No offense intended, but I'm trying to get the message across to you, that if the code that is involved in setting/getting the dropdown value(s) is really that complicated, you might have just found the reason you're having issues.

There are a few general tips I can give you:

1. set up your subscription AFTER setting all the default values.
   There's no reason you need to subscribe to the value of the
   dropdown, before the dropdown is populated. If you find it hard to
   control the moment of subscribing, then again, this a sign your code
   is more complex than it needs to be.
2. .When getting the data, first populate the observableArray that
   supplies the values in the dropdown, and THEN populate the
   observable that sets the value.
3. Dropdown options have values that are always string (because of how
   they are defined in the HTML). If the value-property of your obtions
   isn't a string, conversion might be necessary.

Basically I think in this case, you need 1.